# How to use if/else combined with Automator Loop

Tags: applescript, automator

I've automated the processing of a logo but need to make it possible to process a variable number of logos. I've achieved this with nested applescript in an automator workflow, but the loop does not perform the entire script.

Logos are passed to Incoming folder, the workflow/script changes the desktop to indicate the system is active, grabs the first file, then continues formatting and distributing the file via automator actions. At the end a Loop returns to the beginning until the Incoming folder is empty.

```
set FileAlias to (POSIX file "/Incoming") as alias

tell application "Finder"
    count files of entire contents of FileAlias
    if the result is 0 then

        quit application "_Logos"

        launch application "Reset_Desktop"
    else

        move first item of FileAlias to (POSIX file "/Scripts")

    end if
end tell
```

As you'll see in the script, I'm asking the process to stop if the Incoming folder is empty. This works, but the additional step of resetting the desktop fails to happen. Though if I run the process with no files in the folder to begin with, the desktop does reset.

Comment: May I ask what the full filepaths to the folders `"Incoming"` and `"Scripts"` are ?  From your script, it looks as if your folders are sat in the top-level folder of your hard drive.  There's no reason you would need to create folders here, and it's not generally advised that one should do so.  You might wish to consider moving them to your user home directory, where the path will be `"/Users/%you%/Incoming/"` and `"/Users/%you%/Scripts/"`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The response above lead me there by writing the events to occur in a different order. I also split the Applescript into two; one occurring at the beginning of the workflow, the other appearing at the end, right before the Loop action.

First Applescript:

```
    set FileAlias to (POSIX file "/Incoming") as alias   
    tell application "Finder"
        count files of entire contents of FileAlias
        if the result is 0 then
            null
        else
        move first item of FileAlias to (POSIX file "/Scripts") 
    end if
end tell
```

Second Applescript:

```
set FileAlias to (POSIX file "/Incoming") as alias    
tell application "Finder"       
    count files of entire contents of FileAlias
    if the result is 0 then         
        launch application "Reset_Desktop"
        quit application "Logos"        
    end if      
end tell
```

Comment: When creating and naming variables in AppleScript, there are two preferred methods... The underscore style (for example, `underscore_naming`) and the camel case naming convention (`camelCaseNaming`). This is why I used `set fileAlias` instead of `set FileAlias`, in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know if my solution will work for you because I do not have the two applications you referred to, on my system, to properly test your code.  Also not knowing what your Automator actions are, before and after the AppleScript code, again makes it difficult to provide an exact solution to your question.

Maybe this is along the lines of what you are looking for?

```
set fileAlias to (POSIX file "/Incoming") as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set fileCount to count files of entire contents of fileAlias

    repeat until fileCount is 0
        move first item of fileAlias to (POSIX file "/Scripts")
        delay 0.1
        set fileCount to fileCount - 1
        if fileCount is 0 then
            launch application "Reset_Desktop"
            quit application "_Logos"
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: _"It's difficult to know if my solution will work for you because I do not have the two applications"_  The applications are referenced precisely _once_ each in the script: one being commanded to `launch`; the other to `quit`. Are you saying you have no idea how `launch` and `quit` work? It's such a shame this answer lacks all the merit of the answer from you to another question I liked so much: the OP's script suffers from many pitfalls a novice makes, and you missed an opportunity to really make some good improvements to it, or at least point out its potential flaws.

Comment: Additionally, this script will throw an error if the folder `/Incoming` has any subfolders containing any items in them.  I'll leave you to figure out the why behind that.  Also, does it make sense to have `if fileCount is 0 then...` inside a loop whose condition is `until fileCount is 0` ?  Imagine if you transplant that `if` block to sit outside the repeat loop, and then consider what is left inside the repeat loop; then consider what that repeat loop is doing, and whether you actually need a repeat loop to do that.

Comment: It was unclear to me if  `quit application "_Logos"` was the name of the current Automator workflow app or a completely different app.  However it was obvious to me that `launch` was referring to a separate application. Figuring that his use of the `quit` command may have been his attempt to quit the actual Automator workflow, I figured changing the order of the commands may solve one of the problems.

Comment: Changing the order of the commands is totally fine.  I have zero contention with that at all.  I admit and agree the OP has left a lot of ambiguity in his question and failed to provide the necessary elements to give a good answer.  However, all of issues here causing a sad smiley in my mind are entirely outwith the context of the question, and only relate to the script you've written as a piece of coding.  My suggestion for when an OP fails to give the necessary information is to leave a comment and ask them for clarity and to provide the missing elements.  You'll be able to help more then.

Comment: @wch1zpink Thanks again for helping me solve this. Since I see there's some confusion based on my lack of detail, I'll try to clarify for you and CJK.

Comment: 1. This was my first post and while I am a newb to applescript and automator, I have built several fairly complex workflows over the last 15 years. It's just only ever on an as-needed basis.
2. I'm aware of the issues surrounding subfolders but I avoided providing actual paths in case my company would get mad at me for oversharing. The paths contain client names.
3. My workflow functions 99% as intended, it just wasn't replacing the desktop when more than one file was being processed.

Comment: 4. To fully describe all the details of this workflow would be enormous. I don't feel that I was vague, I just omitted what wasn't necessary.
5. Having said that, here's what the app does. Any number of logos can be dropped into a single folder. These will be the only files, no subfolders will be present. The workflow is called up by an app that begins by changing the desktop background to be solid red with the words "ACTIVE" on it so other users who share the device will not interrupt the workflow.

Comment: The fist logo in the folder is then converted to outlines, scaled to a specific size and output as a jpg, renamed and distributed to an ftp site. Then AppleScript looks to see if the folder is empty. If not, the Loop happens. When it exhausts all the files, the script quits the app from trying to repeat and resets the desktop background to the Inactive version.
6. I tried removing the if/else from my First AppleScript but the process refused to work correctly without first counting the files in fileAlias.
7. Thanks to both of you for the feedback!

Comment: @macaaroni [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is a good reference. I think you would have received more answers and gotten some valuable insight had you included details of the workflow, e.g. a screenshot. What happens before and after a script is often important. We would never have been able to consider splitting the script without seeing the workflow. I get the sense your operation could be streamlined and approached differently. Right now, it feels like these AppleScripts are not doing anything useful, even though you think they are.